# Parsing YouTube API XML response with jQuery for Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, google-maps, youtube-api

I am trying to parse an XML response from the YouTube API with jQuery. My goal is to take the url links and the geotag data from the results and insert markers into a google map. Each marker will have an embedded YouTube video in the infoWindow object. The API request I make to the YouTube servers asks for videos with geotag data within 100km of some coordinates. For now I’m just working with a local file. Does anyone have any suggestions for parsing the XML and adding the videos to a google map? Currently I am trying a multidimensional array approach.
Known problems:
My “latLng” variable is undefined. It’s not supposed to be. This is one of my few leads as to the problem. 
 Any advice?

my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            height: 100%
        }

        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.get("videos.xhtml", "xml", function(xml) {
                $(xml).find("entry").each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).children('id').text();
                    var content = $(this).children('content').text();
                    var vid = $(this).children("link [rel=alternate]").attr("href");
                    var location = $(this).children('georss:where').children('gml:Point').children('gml:pos').text().split(" -").join(",");

                    var marker = new Array(vid, location);
                    var markers = new Array();
                    markers.push(marker);
                    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0][1]);
                    var markers = new Array();
                    var myOptions = {
                        zoom: 19,
                        center: latLng,
                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

                    //var vidString = '<div style="width:450; height: 400;"><object width="425" height="355"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/2A-fuFeRekE&rel=1"></param><param name="wmode" value="transparent"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/2A-fuFeRekE&rel=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="425" height="355"></embed></object></div>';
                    //use arrays
                    for (a = 0; a < markers.length; a++) {
                        var vidArray = new Array(markers[a][0]);
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: vidArray
                            // is not emebeded
                        });
                    }

                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: markers[i][1],
                            map: map,
                            title: "Hello World"
                        });
                        var marker1 = Array();
                        marker1.push(newMarker);
                    }
                    for (b = 0; b < markers.length; b++) {
                        // how do I make it add more marker listener
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker1[b], "click", function(){
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker1[b])
                        });
                    }

                    alert(vid);
                });
            });
        });

        //I need to convert to a string
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as for the XML file you should be aware of the "same origin policy". This means that you can't load a XML or JSON file from another server (in theory).

However, jQuery offers the jsonP-function to get around this or you can try the alternative jquery-jsonp script.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/

bye.

Comment: Thannks, I am aware of that limitation, but for now I am using a static xml file on my hard drive. I'm just trying to get the concept to work. Any suggestions concerning my code itself?